# I cannot display and/or change content with pagify.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins, url-rewriting

I have found a plugin called pagify that I would like to use. [GITHUB](https://github.com/cmpolis/Pagify)

You can see a working demonstation here: http://www.bytemuse.com/Pagify/

I have downloaded the whole thing from github and uploaded it to my own website. But I simply can't get it to work. And I have no idea why. I also tried go grapping the recourses from the bytemuse website instead. But with the same result. I can't shake the feeling that there's something huge that I'm missing. That why I'm seeking your help.

You can see my attempt here: http://rplambech.dk/Pagify-master/demo/

The URL changes fine, but I cannot get it to show content. Therefor, it's also impossible for me we to check if the browsers back button works. (which is why I wan't this plugin)

I have done everything that I was supposed to. (At least I think so) According to http://www.bytemuse.com/Pagify/#usage

I've created the div.

```
<div id='page_holder' />
```

And done the javascript:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#page_holder').pagify({
          pages: ['about_p', 'usage', 'options'],
          animation: 'fadeIn',
          'default': 'about_p',
          cache: true
        });
      });
    </script>
```

And set up my links:

```
      <nav>
        <a href="#about">About</a>
        <a href="#usage">Usage</a>
        <a href="#options">Options</a>
      </nav>
```

I don't think that I understand the logic here. page_holder will include my about page fx. if I click on that link?

I have the about page online as well: http://rplambech.dk/Pagify-master/demo/about.html

Should I include is somehow differently?

Is there something wrong with what I have done, or does the problem lie in the pagify.js?

I really hope that one of you can help me clear this up. I simply do not understand what it is that I'm doing wrong, since everything looks to be exactly the same, as on the bytemuse site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open Firebug (Console) you will see 2 errors :

```
GET http://rplambech.dk/about.html 404 (Not Found) jquery-1.6.4.min.js:4
GET http://rplambech.dk/usage.html 404 (Not Found) jquery-1.6.4.min.js:4
```

It seems that the script is looking for the .html pages in the root folder. Try to move the html pages to the root folder and see if it work.

Edit:
add the option `basePagePath: 'http://rplambech.dk/Pagify-master/demo/'` after `cache: true,` will resolve the problem.

Here is a full setup for your example:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#page_holder').pagify({
      pages: ['about_p', 'usage', 'options'],
      animation: 'fadeIn',
      'default': 'about_p',
      cache: true,
      basePagePath: 'http://rplambech.dk/Pagify-master/demo/'
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I will try this a bit later. :-) And eccept if it works.